# Count unique values that have a partial text match

Tags: excel, count

I'm using `=SUMPRODUCT((E23:E4000<>"")/COUNTIF(E23:E4000,E23:E4000&""))` to count the unique values of a large list which works fine

However I want excel to NOT count these values if the cell it's counting has a partial text match of _A and _B

For example

```
1
1
1
1
1_A
1_A
2
2
3
```

The formula will count 4 values but I only want it to count 3.

Thanks for anyhelp

Comment: Are you just looking for an Excel formula? Maybe add an Excel tag to your question, and remove arrays.

Comment: You example makes no sense - how would that count 4 values, and how would you want that to count 3? I would expect it to count 8 values, but you want it to only count 6.

Comment: They want the distinct count excluding  blah _ blah so 1,2,3. And title doesn't match description. So guess excluding with IsNumber Search "_"

Comment: @QHarr Ahh I see now...

Comment: Seems OP wandered off anyways. And the title still is out of kilter with question body.

Comment: Sorry I'm in England so I'm only just back in work. I want UNIQUE values (the total of which is 4 in the example) but I don't want a unique value to be calculated if there is a "_A" or "_B" or "_C" in the name so the actual total counted would be 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like (assuming your above data sample was in A1:A9)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A9<>""),
--NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_",A1:A9,1)))/COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9&"")
)
```

And for your formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E23:E4000<>""),--NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_",E23:E4000,1)))/COUNTIF(E23:E4000,E23:E4000&""))
```

Comment: Remove the NOT if you actually wanted the _ strings.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(E23:E4000)/COUNTIF(E23:E4000,E23:E4000&""))
```

to count only unique instances of number strings (so ignores any data point that contains `_`).

Comment: I should have seen that simplification :-( Nice

Comment: This didn't work for me, I should have made my example more clear. The names have other text characters in. That's my fault hence the -1 on my question ha

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function KountUniq(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant
    Dim c As Collection

    Set c = New Collection

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(1, v, "_") = 0 And v <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            c.Add v, CStr(v)
                On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next r

    KountUniq = c.Count
End Function
```